# Separar una cadena en partes

Tags: c#, webforms

Hola necesito separar la cadena de nombre completo : 
en..

textbox--> nombre

textbox--> apellido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito retornarlo aquí estado intentando esto ..

```
EmpleadoBL empleadoBL = new EmpleadoBL();
List<EmpleadoEL> lista = empleadoBL.ConsultarEmpleado(id);
ddlEmpresaR1.SelectedValue = lista[0].cod_emp;
txtnom1.Text = lista[0].nombre_completo.Split(' ').ToString();
```

Comment: El método `Split` devuelve un `string[]`. Si quieres devolver el primer elemento, debes hacer `txtnom1.Text = lista[0].nombre_completo.Split(' ')[0].ToString();`. Ten en cuenta que debes comprobar que `lista[0].nombre_completo`tenga algo o te lanzará una excepción

Comment: gracias ... y si fuera kevin arturo .. y quiero retornar los dos nombres..

Comment: Deberías definir tus nombres y apellidos en campos independientes en la base de datos, ya que es muy difícil diferenciar cual es el nombre y cual es el apellido solo teniendo el texto. Inclusive puede que en algunos casos se te presente que el apellido vendrá en la primera posición.

Answer (score 0):

El método [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) devuelve un `string[]`. Esto significa que si haces un `ToString()` al resultado de un `Split`, lo que vas a obtener es el nombre de la clase (`System,String[]`).

Si quieres devolver el primer elemento, debes indicar el indice de la cadena a devolver:

```
txtnom1.Text = lista[0].nombre_completo.Split(' ')[0].ToString();
```

Ten en cuenta que debes comprobar que lista[0].nombre_completotenga algo o te lanzará una excepción

> y si fuera kevin arturo .. y quiero retornar los dos nombres?

Eso es un problema diferente y un poco mas complejo, ya que ... como sabes si el nombre es sencillo o compuesto? No hay una solución fácil. Podrías comprobar el tamaño del `string[]` devuelto por `Split` y si es 4, devolver los dos primeros elementos como el nombre. Pero...y si resulta que lo que es compuesto es el apellido?. Me temo que no hay una solución para ello que cubra todos los caso, mas allá de gestionarlo en la entrada de datos (al pedir los datos, almacenar el nombre en un campo y los apellidos en otro).